# is it possible to animate and remove the pseudo content from a element..?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations, pseudo-element

I have a button, when a user click on the button, i am adding a "tick" mark on the button using pseudo content `:before`, it works fine.

But i need to remove that `:before` property by `fadeOut()` with 2sec. is it possible to do that?

here is my button css code:

```
button{
    border: 1px solid #1f85c3;
    height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: .4em 1em !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#1f96d0, #007cc2);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
}
```

on click i am adding a class name `right`:

```
button.right:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0%;
    margin: -7px 0 0 -10px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 16px;
    border: solid #FFF;
    border-width: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

any advice please?

Comment: jQuery cannot access psuedo elements, so cannot be used to do what you need.

Comment: if you are using jQuery, why not just prepend an element and then animate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the `right` class on click, you could create an empty `:before` pseudo-element for the button and use transitions

```
button:before{
    content:'';
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 2s linear;
}
```

and add `opacity:0` to your `button.right:before` rule.

```
button.right:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0%;
    margin: -7px 0 0 -10px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 16px;
    border: solid #FFF;
    border-width: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

    opacity:0;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/SYQ89/

(*i have only added the standard property for transitions, you should add vendor specific prefixes if required..*)